# Deployment Error in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, ear

When deploying an EAR in Jboss, the application fails to start and throws the following stack trace:

```
16:33:31,804 WARN  [EntityResolver] Entity is not registered, publicId=-//Sun  Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application Client 1.2//EN systemId=http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application-client_1_2.dtd    
16:33:32,112 ERROR [XmlFileLoader] The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the  document type declaration must be well-formed.:2:1
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.    
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.metadata.XmlFileLoader.getDocument(XmlFileLoader.java:313)
at org.jboss.metadata.XmlFileLoader.getDocument(XmlFileLoader.java:257)
at org.jboss.deployment.ClientDeployer.start(ClientDeployer.java:122)
~~~ snip ~~~
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:242)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
at $Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
```

Could this be related to a library / jar used by my application?

Answer (score 1):

This is the key:

> The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type
>   declaration must be well-formed.

This is known to occur when a corrupt, missing or inaccessible DTD is referred to.

First, look at the service descriptor XML is valid. If so, as a test, remove the DTD and try again.

If your application (or a library) is trying to validate a document by reading the DTD from the internet, JBoss will need internet access. Add `-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourproxy` if you're using a proxy. You can also check that the DTD's are actually on-line and available, which can cause the same symptom.

[Related JBoss issue on Jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7974)